# Yii2 behavior in controller don't work

Tags: php, yii2, basic-authentication, behavior

I have properly working controller and I want to attach there a behavior of basic auth. I add method `behaviors()` to controller and `var_dump($this->behaviors);` in before action. Everything is correct. Problem is that `HttpBasicAuth` doesnt work with method.

Here's my code:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'basicAuth' => [
            'class' => \yii\filters\auth\HttpBasicAuth::className(),
            'auth' => function ($username, $password) {
                if (! $this->isValidUser($username, $password)) {
                    return User::findByUsername($username);
                }

                return false;
            }
        ],

    ];
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

guys, I solved this bug.

If we want to call behaviors and we have beforeAction metohd in our controller.
Your `beforeAction` should look like. Method which calls behaviors located in method `beforeAction` of parent class.

```
public function beforeAction($event)
{
    ...

    return parent::beforeAction($event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`auth` param should be a key of `basicAuth` array :

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'basicAuth' => [
            'class' => \yii\filters\auth\HttpBasicAuth::className(),
            'auth' => function ($username, $password) {
                // ...
            }
        ],
    ];
}
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-auth-httpbasicauth.html

Comment: Yeap, I changed, but still the same. I will copy and paste new code in question

Comment: It was the correct answer to your first question... How could I guess that you had a wrong beforeAction method ?...